# Annotating derived database clolumns in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

In our database table, we record a large string and its corresponding md5 value.  In mysql5, we insert such a record with

```
insert (md5,content) values (md5(content), hex(content));
```

Moving to hibernate, I have annotated the entity

```
@Column(name = "content", columnDefinition = "MEDIUMTEXT")
@ColumnTransformer(read = "unhex(content)", write="hex(?)")
private String content;
```

which works great.  But I don't see how to annotate the md5 column so that it can be automatically generated on insert.  In particular, a columntransformer won't work, since the ? in the annotation refers to the md5 field, not the content field.

Any observations, or help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hibernate interceptors and exactly pre-save (in this case) events for encryption.
read about hibernate interceptors here [Hibernate Interceptors](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/events.html)

Comment: I appreciate this answer.  I learned something that I did not know.  However, I don't think that this approach can solve my problem.  I can intercept onSave, and find the state (value) and propertynames from my query, but it is not obvious to me how to set the value.  If I set the value for the md5 field to be "md5(content)", that literal string is inserted, where obviously,I want to compute the md5.